# How do I declare a member function for a class that contains a struct?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make this code compile, but I can't seem to get the syntax for it right. I want to make this function a member function of the bst class. The Node struct and FindMin work fine with each other outside of a class, but I can't make the declaration work within.

```
//class bst
//{
    public:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *left;
        struct Node *right;
    };

    //struct FindMin(Node*);

//};

//Function to find minimum in a tree.
Node* FindMin(Node* root)
{
    while(root->left != NULL) root = root->left;
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the member function just like any other. `Node` is declared in the scope of the class so you can refer to it directly.

If you put the definition outside of the class body you will have to specify the full scope for the return value.

```
class bst
{
    public:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *left;
        struct Node *right;
    };

    Node* FindMin(Node*);

};

bst::Node* bst::FindMin(Node* root) {
    // ...  
}
```